# Data binding custom control with parent

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a UserControl that contains a listbox.

On the parent window, I have this UserControl and a button.

Ideally I'd like to use the ChangePropertyAction behavior on the parents button, and tie it to the UserControl's listbox count.

The idea being that if there are no entries in the listbox inside the usercontrol, the button on the parent window is hidden. The listbox is bound to an observablecollection.

Do I create a DependencyProperty to do this? I'm not sure how to bind the listbox's count to this property though.

Thanks so much for any insight into the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Messenger classes from the MVVM Futures project to let the UserControl's ViewModel signal other ViewModels of the change.

This let's multiple listeners monitor for the same changes, without the need for extra Dependency Properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ElementName` Binding to reach the `ListBox` state from the `Button`. You then want to use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to do the magic.

Like so:

```
<Window x:Class="NestedTreeTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="200" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=myList, Path=HasItems, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                Text
        </Button>
        <ListBox x:Name="myList">
            <!--<ListBoxItem>Item A</ListBoxItem>-->
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

comment out, or uncomment the `ListBoxItems` to see it working...

Comment: Thank you for the help. The problem though is the listbox is inside a UserControl. So on Window1, It's more:

<StackPanel>
                <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=myList, Path=HasItems, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                Text
                </Button>
                <Controls:MyControl />
        </StackPanel>

And I need to bind to a listbox in MyControl. I'm not sure how to expose that from the UserControl is the issue.